# Laravel retrieve a cookie value

Tags: php, laravel, cookies

I am doing the following in my laravel app,

```
$unique_id = uniqid();
return redirect($response['_links']['next_url']['href'])->withCookie(cookie($unique_id, $response['payment_id'], 20));
```

Once the redirect has been done, how I would get the value of the cookie, as when I do this,

```
$debug = [
      'uuid' => $request->query('uuid'),
      'payment_id' => $request->cookie($request->query('uuid'))
    ];
    dd($debug);
```

The uuid is the `$unique_id` that get passed into to the redirection url, so I assumed access it like above would work but no, how can I access the value of the cookie?

A cookie with uuid is getting created and has a value,

[image]

Comment: is `$request->query('uuid')` set?

Comment: yes it is, I get the apprpriate uniq id from the URL fine.

Comment: check if cookie name is same as the `uuid`